# Oracle 20 million update based on join

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

I have a need to do the following

```
  UPDATE TABLE2 t2
SET t2.product_id = (select t1.product_id from
table1 t1 where t1.matching_id = t2.matching_id)
```

Except that TABLE2 has 27 million records. The product_id is a newly added column and hence populating data to it.
I could use a cursor , break down my record set in TABLE2 to a reasonably smaller number, But with 27 million records, I am not sure whats the best way.
Pl suggest, even if it means exporting my data to excel.

Update - THe matching columns are indexed too.

Comment: I think that is the right way to do it as long you have a right index for `matching_id`. Did you try it? any error?

Comment: for 3 million records, it took 30 minutes. I did not try for 27 million. Not feasible if it takes 30*9 minutes:)

Comment: Do you have index for matching_id? On both tables

Comment: What is the size of the `table1` ?

Comment: If time is not a constraint, wrap it in to a DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER (see [CREATE_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#i1009099)) and let it run.

Comment: Even the size is table 1 is 9 million odd records

Comment: The object of this exercise is denormalizing PRODUCT_ID.  What benefit do you think you'll get from this?  There may be other ways of achieving that benefit.

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN PLAN for the update.  How many `table1.matching_id` actually match `table2.matching_id`?

Comment: Updating 20M out of 27M is a really bad idea. Doing it via an index is an even worse idea! Use the CTAS as suggested by @Juan-carlos-oropez below.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could do different is replace the update for a `CREATE TABLE AS`

```
  CREATE TABLE table2_new AS
        SELECT t2.* (less product_id), t1.product_id
        FROM table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.matching_id = t2.matching_id
```

But later you will have to add the `CONSTRAINTS` manually, delete `table2` and replace for `table2_new`

Comment: I can try this, But yea lot of drop and recreate constraint, index, default values etc,

Comment: The CTAS (Create table .. as select) is probably the right answer. You may be able to employ some parallelism too, providing you have sufficient CPU and IO resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
update (select t1.product_id as old_product_id, t2.product_id as new_product_id
        from table1 t1
        join table2 t2 on (t1.matching_id = t2.matching_id)) t
set t.new_product_id = t.old_product_id
```